# Converting Python Dict to JSON for MySQL field of JSON type

Tags: python, mysql, json

I am currently getting this error:

```
Invalid JSON text: "not a JSON text, may need CAST" at position 0 in value for column
```

This is the value that is trying to be inserted:

```
{
    "ath": 69045, 
    "ath_date": "2021-11-10T14:24:11.849Z", 
    "atl": 67.81, 
    "atl_date": "2013-07-06T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

When trying to insert into my database. I believe it is due to malformed JSON however I am using `json.dumps()` to convert my dictionary. I have tried several things I have found over the last few hours to try and format it correctly but am hitting a wall between two errors.

I tried adding another level as well as wrapping it all in an array as that was recommended in another question, however, that produced the same error.

My Dict:

```
        ticker_market_data[ticker] = {
            "all_time": {
                "ath": market_data["ath"]["usd"],
                "ath_date": market_data["ath_date"]["usd"],
                "atl": market_data["atl"]["usd"],
                "atl_date": market_data["atl_date"]["usd"],
            },
            "price_change_percent": {
                "1h": market_data["price_change_percentage_1h_in_currency"]["usd"],
                "24h": market_data["price_change_percentage_24h"],
                "7d": market_data["price_change_percentage_7d"],
                "30d": market_data["price_change_percentage_30d"],
                "1y": market_data["price_change_percentage_1y"],
            },
        }
```

The problem items being `all_time` and `price_change_percent`.

This is how I am creating the variables to store in the database:

```
        all_time = json.dumps(ticker_market_data[ticker].get("all_time"))
        price_change_percent = json.dumps(ticker_market_data[ticker].get("price_change_percent"))
```

Comment: How are you inserting those values? Also post the contents of `all_time` or `price_change_percent` (depending on which one causes the error).

Comment: Show the value which you try to insert into MySQL table. *I am currently getting this error* This is NOT MySQL error message.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated to include the value being inserted. In this case it is all_time as that is the first one to be tried.

Comment: That is a print of the json.dumps()

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to answer my own question though I don't know how much it will benefit the community as it was completely on me. My code posted above was entirely correct, the problem lay in the order of variables being inserted in the SQL. I had the wrong type of variable one position up from where it needed to be. So rather than JSON being inserted into the column it was a float.